# testng IAnnotationTransformer not evaluating condition while disabling test on run time

Tags: selenium, testng

My code is something like below:

```
public class A implements IAnnotationTransformer {

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        testNG.setAnnotationTransformer(new A());
}

@Test
public void testA() throws Exception {
//do some steps and evaluate condition "toBeSkipped" , which results in 
//either "true" or "false" string values.
}

@Override
public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        if ("testA".equals(testMethod.getName())) {
            if ( !toBeSkipped.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                annotation.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have mentioned the listener in my testng.xml.

Problem- When I start my test , it doesn't execute test method "testA()" first, but goes to transform() method first and throws nullPointer exception on the line "`!toBeSkipped.equalsIgnoreCase("true")`" stating "toBeSkipped" flag is null. This is because it doesn't evaluate the condition since it doesn't execute the test.

Comment: IAnnotationTransformer are used to modify annotation before the test is run. Also you would be better off creating a standalone class for the IAnnotationTransformer  and not mixing with test annotations.

Comment: ok, Thanks.Then this won't solve my problem. I had to decide whether to run further tests based on a condition which would be evaluated in first test (testA).

I had created separate class to implement IAnnotationTransformer, but the behaviour was same.